# How Can Get value from Latest line in one2many filed basen for the same product

Tags: odoo

I'm added one2many field named final cost line in landed cost view to create records from Adjustment lines automatically  but i want to get latest line for each product in Adjustment lines 
for example if i have in Adjustment lines Product x and 2 lines in cost lines so in Adjustment lines system will create 2 lines 
how can get value in second line when system create final cost line 
and if i have 2 products in Adjustment lines system get the latest value for each product in final cost line
this my code
query = """SELECT x.move_id, x.product_id, x.quantity,x.cost_id, x.former_cost, x.additional_landed_cost,x.final_cost_unit as final_cost FROM stock_valuation_adjustment_lines x WHERE x.cost_id=%s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"""%(self.id) self.env.cr.execute(query)

Comment: please post your modols.

Comment: You don't need to use sql querry